# how to join elements (chars) from a list into a single element in R?

Tags: r, genetics

I'm trying to create a simple script in R to simulate environmental pressure on genes so I have this following random generator of ATCG:

```
list <- c("A","T","C","G")
samp <- sample(list, 1000, replace = T)
display <- function(a,b,c) {
    result <- sample(list, 1000, replace = T)
    return(result)
}

a <- display(a)

b <- display(b)

c <- display(c)
```

The code is working fine but is conceptually wrong because the codon need to be joined as a group of characters not by a single one.
So my question is, how to join this elements (1:4,5:8,...107:110) ?

I know there's many packages about genetics in R but I'm trying to keep it very simple just to use as an exercise on my genetics study group.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, 1) why do you put function(a,b,c) if your function is neither a function of a, b or c but only some replication. Your function is function() sample(list, 1000, replace = TRUE) 2) it's unclear what you want. You want a string vector of words with 4 characters each words ?

Comment: 3) list is not a list but a string vector

Comment: Hi, answering 1) I just made the function so it can run a different sample for each vector 2) yes, each string with 4 characters from the list sample (ATCG). 3) sorry for the misconception but if it was a question I didn't get 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you had in mind:

```
dat <- setNames( data.frame(
  replicate(3, replicate( 1000,
  paste0(sample(c("A","C","T","G"),4, replace=T),collapse="") ) ) ),
  c("a","b","c") )
```

Result

```
dat
      a    b    c
1  CATG CTAG CGAT
2  AGCT GACT TGAC
3  TCAG TAGC TCAG
4  CGAT GACT GTAC
5  TCGA TAGC CTGA
...etc
```

You should be able to do the comparisons with `dat$a`,`dat$b` and `dat$c`

Comment: Sorry I cant vote your answer but is almost it. I need an output like this:
>a = ([ATCG],[ATTA],[GGAT],...)
>b = ([TATA],[GTTA],[GGAT],...)

so I can compare a ~ b

Comment: Made some edits. This should work now.

Comment: oh boy you made it! very thanks!

Comment: but I just note that every codon have exactly one element of each (ATCG) in a different order, could have some argument that make possible to repeat an element in each element like (AACG or CCTG) ?

Comment: Just added it. Try again. Must have been dropped before while copy pasting.

Comment: Hey I did not see the comment at the end of the question. Why did you delete the answer? It is a correct answer. please undelete it. so as to upvote. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935389/creating-a-new-column-in-dataframe-using-row-values-as-variables-in-a-function-i/69935529?noredirect=1#comment123626120_69935681)

Comment: I didn't delete the answer my friend

Comment: @Arthur Occhiutto The comment is from another user regarding another post. No idea why it appeared here.